# Using Perl::SFTP::Foreign count files via ls()

Tags: perl, sftp

Using Perl::SFTP::Foreign I'm trying to count the number of files with a specific file handle.

Usage of the result is to incrementally number files during a rename command later in the code such that the first zip file gets renamed filename.zip.bak, then filename.zip.bak2 then filename.zip.bak3

```
my $file = "filename.zip"
$reName  = ".bak";

@rls = $sftp->ls('.', wanted => qr/$file.*/ );    
$rls_size = @rls;
$fileReName = $file . $reName;


if ( $rls_size > 1 ) {
    $fileReName = $fileReName . $rls_size ;
}

unless ( $sftp->rename($file, $fileReName) ) {
    Print "Error Renaming $file to $fileReName. $@ $!\n");
}
```

I'm sorry for the formatting. Code keeps returning one entry in the array so as to not assign a number beyond 1 even if there are 2 or more that would normally be picked in the count. Is there something wrong with the wanted statement and the formatting of the given regex expectation?

Here is the old Net::FTP code that was used to perform the same function:

```
sub process_file($)
{   my $file = $_[0];

    if($reName)
    {   
        @rls = $ftp->ls($file."*");
        $rls_size = @rls;
        $fileReName = $file . $reName;
        if($rls_size > 1){  $fileReName = $fileReName . $rls_size;  }

        unless ($ftp->rename($file,$fileReName))
        {   PrintLog (0, "Error Renaming $file to $fileReName. $@ $!\n");   
            $error =101;
            exit 101;
        }else{  PrintLog (7, "Renamed File $file to $fileReName.\n");   }
    }
    else{
        unless ($ftp->delete($file))
        {   PrintLog (0, "Error deleting $file. $@ $!\n");  
            $error =101;    
            exit 101;
        }else{  PrintLog (7, "Deleted $file.\n");   }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please try to spell the names of modules correctly. Do you mean `Net::SFTP::Foreign`? `Perl SFTP Foreign` doesn't make sense.

Comment: *"I'm sorry for the formatting"* Don't be sorry, just fix it. If you don't do it then I will have to, and that's not very fair when you're already getting free professional help.

Comment: `Perl:SFTP:Foreign` doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score -1):

If you're really using `Net::SFTP::Foreign` then this line is wrong.

```
@rls = $sftp->ls('.',wanted=> qr/$file.*/ );
```

The documentation says that the `ls` method returns a *reference to an array of hashes*

Comment: In a past version of code, a previous developer used Net::FTP to perform the same function, but I understand the modules are different. They used the LS command in FTP to return an array and then assigned that array to a single variable which acted as a counting mechanism and incrementally increased the .bak* files appropriately. I am attempting to perform the same functionality.

Answer (score -1):

By changing the command from ls() to using find() it has corrected the issue. Specifically the following code was replaced

From

`@rls = $sftp->ls('.', wanted => qr/$file.*/ );`

To

`@rls = $sftp->find('.',wanted=> qr/^$file.*/ );`

This has successfully generated an array of the size expected. This appears to be a difference between ls (single array of hashes) vs. find (list of hashes).

Comment: That is because `find` returns a list of hashes instead of the array reference from `ls` that I described. This is the *wrong solution* because `find` is *recursive* and will include all matching files in the given directory or *anywhere in the directories beneath it*, so you may well find many more files than you expect. Stick to `ls`.